# how to create a meeting in English using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I create a meeting using Teams or Outlook directly, the info is something like:

```
Join Microsoft Teams Meeting

+xx xxxx   China, All locations (Toll)

Conference ID: xxx xxx#

Local numbers | Reset PIN | Learn more about Teams | Meeting options
```

But when I use the graph api to create the meeting(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events), the info will be in Chinese like:

```
欢迎加入会议

+xx xxxx   中国, ....
....
```

I don't want to create the meeting in Chinese, how should I use the graph api?

Comment: Sounds like a locale issue. Just to isolate the issue, give a try in Microsoft Graph Explorer and see if you can repro the issue.

Comment: You can use the Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration cmdlet to view the regional settings of a mailbox. You can view the date format, time format, time zone, and language of the mailbox.

Comment: @Dev Yes, the Microsoft Graph Exploer also create a meeting in Chinese